# Left join and chose matching columns from right table only

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames containing n columns each(1 Id and n-1 numeric cols).  I am joining(left join) two data frames using the Id column. Since n-1 columns are in both data frames I am having (n-1).x and (n-1).y columns from both  dataframes.

How can I drop all (n-1).x and retain (n-1).y columns only in dplyr?

```
dataA<-data.frame(ID=c("1","b","c"),Val=c(1,2,3))
dataB<-data.frame(ID=c("1","b","c"),Val=c(4,5,6))
data<-dataA %>% left_join(dataB,by=c("ID"="ID"))
data
#  ID Val.x Val.y
#1  1     1     4
#2  b     2     5
#3  c     3     6
```

Kindly assume that `Val` is `Val1`, `Val2` and so on till `Val`n-1.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can join and drop the columns ends with '.x'.

```
dataA %>%
left_join(dataB, by=c('ID'='ID')) %>%
select(-ends_with(".x"))

  ID Val.y
1  1     4
2  b     5
3  c     6
```

Or you can select only 'id' column from left data frame and join it.

```
dataA%>%
select(ID) %>%
left_join(dataB, by=c('ID'='ID'))

   ID Val
1  1   4
2  b   5
3  c   6
```